# Python Dictionary inside a list (pulling individual values)

Tags: python, excel, list, dictionary

I have a list containing dictionaries-

```
[{'Name of Business' : 'Amazon', 'Contact Name' : 'Jeff Bezos', 'Email' : 'Jeff@Amazon.com'},
 { {'Name of Business' : 'Microsoft', 'Contact Name' : 'Bill Gates', 'Email' : 'Bill@Microsoft.com'}]
```

I will later need to save each Name of Business, Contact Name etc into a variable or have an easy way to call them for reuse.

I found that using something like

```
for x in dict_list:
   print x["Client"], x['Contact Name'], x['Email']
```

Gives me printout of all the data:
Amazon Jeff Bezos Jeff@Amazon.com
Microsoft Bill Gates Bill@Microsoft.com

But what if i just want the info from the first entry?
What if I want to save the data from each dictionary entry to a separate variable?

Using

```
 first_entry = dict_list[0]  
 print first_entry["Client"], first_entry['Contact Name'], first_entry['Email']
```

But there has to be some way to do this in one line without creating another variable first?

Thanks for any help I can get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't create the variable:

```
print dict_list[0]["Client"], dict_list[0]['Contact Name'], dict_list[0]['Email']
```

or in a loop:

```
idx = [1]
for i in idx:
    print dict_list[i]["Client"], dict_list[i]['Contact Name'], dict_list[i]['Email']
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate two different examples of a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
print dict_list[0]["Client"], dict_list[0]['Contact Name'], dict_list[0]['Email']
```

Comment: Thanks I knew this could be done but was having troubles figuring out the exact syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the structure you employ to store the data. I would recommend to use a pandas dataframe to handle your data according to the operations you need:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(l)
#Out[5]: 
#  Contact Name               Email Name of Business
#0   Jeff Bezos     Jeff@Amazon.com           Amazon
#1   Bill Gates  Bill@Microsoft.com        Microsoft
```

*Each dictionary entry corresponds to a colum.*
You can access the first entry as a series:

```
df['Name of Business']         
#Out[9]: 
#0       Amazon
#1    Microsoft
#Name: Name of Business, dtype: object
```

Or as a list:

```
df['Name of Business'].tolist()
#Out[8]: ['Amazon', 'Microsoft']
```

Comment: Interesting. I will have to look into Pandas. Thanks for your response!

Comment: it will avoid you a lot of useless loops and comprehension lists :)

Answer (score 1):

> What if I want to save the data from each dictionary entry to a separate variable?

You can use a list comprehension or `map()` for this, e.g. for the first list element:

```
client, contact, email = map(dict_list[0].get, ("Client", "Contact Name", "Email"))
```

Comment: Thanks Im fairly new to Python and will look further into the map command!